# Enable_categorical is not working with categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have several categorical features in my dataset and I have set their data type to "category".

```
cols = ['A','B', 'C']
for i in cols:
        data[i] = data[i].astype('category')
```

and I have created the XGboost instance like this

```
model_xgb = XGBClassifier(**xgb_params, scale_pos_weight=weight, tree_method='hist', enable_categorical=True)
```

But when I run the model it gives me an error saying:

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category. 
When categorical type is supplied, The experimental DMatrix parameter enable_categorical 
must be set to True.  Invalid columns:A: category, B: category, C: category
```